# Alternative to UIWebView for showing formatted posts

Tags: ios, uiwebview, core-text

Well I found many discussions in google that UIWebView is bad. I'm trying to create a ios app that will show forum (bulletin board) topic/posts. Safari is slow showing them so i was planing to use ATOM feed to show the topics in a native ios app. Now the thing is, in ATOM feed, the posts are in html. showing them in a webview is same as browsing the site with mobile safari(even worst bcz of absence of nitro engine). So i think i should convert/parse the html and then show them using core text.
Will that be fast ? and should i convert/parse the html inside the app or use server side parsing ? if i parse inside the app, will that be laggy ? 
Is there any library available that renders html using core text ? my html will be fairly simple, just bold italic underline and sometimes image. (font size is same all the  time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Coconetics' [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText). I have not used it personally but I thing it does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is indeed a great find.I passed a html document full of non-english letters and unfortunately it seems more slow than UIWebView.Maybe some adjustment with fonts need. Thanks again :)